# Maven: 1.7.4 openejb dependancy fails

Tags: maven, tomcat, apache-tomee, openejb, artifact

**Wanted to make use of openejb on top of tomcat v7 using maven instead of installing tomee**. Referring to Apache documentation, 3 dependencies have to be added to the maven project.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.openejb</groupId>
    <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
    <version>6.0-6</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.openejb</groupId>
    <artifactId>openejb-core</artifactId>
    <version>4.7.4</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.openejb</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomee</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.4</version>
</dependency>
```

but the last depency generates following error: **Missing artifact org.apache.openejb:tomee:jar:1.7.4**

Comment: could somebody explains the downvote?

Answer (score 1):

The correct artifactId being visible in:
http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.openejb/apache-tomee/1.7.4 
is **apache-tomee** and not **tomee**
so, replace the last depency by the following one and the problem will be solved:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.openejb</groupId>
    <artifactId>apache-tomee</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.4</version>
</dependency>
```